# PHP: Capitalize imported text

Tags: php, mysql, xml

In a php script I have the following command:

```
$data['city'] = htmlspecialchars((string)$row->{get($row, 'CPVILLE')}->CPVILLE, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

It imports from a XML file a text to a mysql database.

There is no problem, except that the source text is in uppercase. I need it capitalized in order to respect the right format for the website.

How could I edit this command to transform the text as capitalized?

Comment: http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *capitalized*?

Comment: what do you want capitalize or uppercase??

Comment: The source text in the XML is in uppercase. For instance: LONDON. I need to import the text as "London".

Comment: use this `ucwords(htmlspecialchars((string)$row->{get($row, 'CPVILLE')}->CPVILLE, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));`

Comment: Well, the imported text is now in UPPERCASE format. Not what was expected... :/
so  I've made a small modification and I solved it:

`$data['city'] = ucwords(strtolower(htmlspecialchars((string)$row->{get($row, 'CPVILLE')}->CPVILLE, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));`

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
    $your_string = ucwords($your_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ucwords ()`

**Example**

```
$string = 'Your string';
echo ucwords($string); // Output: Your String
```

More information is available in the PHP Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Another method is to use `strtoupper ( $string )`

**Example**

```
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtoupper($str);
echo $str; // Prints MARY HAD A LITTLE LAMB AND SHE LOVED IT SO
```

Documentation on the usage of `strtoupper` is available here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

If you just want to capitalise the first letter in a string then use: `ucfirst()`

**Example**

```
$string = 'ThIs Is My StRiNg';
echo ucfirst ( $string ); // Output: This is my string
```

More information is available: http://php.net/ucfirst

Comment: `$string = 'Your String';
echo ucwords($string); // Output: Your String` Capitalize and uppercase are totally different.